# Necessary but not Sufficient Existence Condition for Killing Spinors

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry, supersymmetry, spinors

A Killing spinor is defined by the Killing equations:

$$D_{\mu}\epsilon=\partial_{\mu}\epsilon + \frac{1}{4}{\omega_{\mu}}^{ab}\gamma_{ab}=0$$

From this we can derive the Necessary but not Sufficient Existence Condition for Killing Spinors:

$$\frac{1}{8}{R^{ab}}_{\mu \nu}\gamma_{ab}\epsilon=[D_{\mu},D_{\nu}]\epsilon=0$$

My question is:

If we suppose, for example, that the Necessary but not Sufficient Existence Condition for Killing Spinors is satisfied only for the Null Spinor, does this means that only this Null Spinor satisfies the Killing Equation $D_{\mu}\epsilon=0$?

Or more in general:

Since it is a Necessary but not Sufficient Existence Condition, does this mean that there can't be any more solution to the Killing Equation other that the ones that satisfies the satisfies the last condition $\frac{1}{8}{R^{ab}}_{\mu \nu}\gamma_{ab}\epsilon=0$?

Comment: Killing Spinors are essentially twistors (see the definition in section 6.6 of Spinors and Spacetime, Vol-II). The Weyl curvature produces restriction on solution of Killing Spinor (see the article by B. Jeffryes , page 12 in [Twistor Newsletter No15 11 Jan 1983](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/lmason/Tn/TN1-25/))